# Pass the dictionary to next page after cleaning the POST data

Tags: django, forms

```
I have a form A() on first page with url /A/.
I have a form b() on second page with url /B/.
```

If my `A()` data is cleaned on first page,I want to pass the data to page B.

I use `A()` to validate input but do not save it to database.
I require first page details on second page.

Code

**first_page/view.py**

```
main(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
   f  = A(request.POST)
   if f.is_valid():
      return render()   //how can I pass the cleaned data to second page???
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Form Wizards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).  They are designed for chaining multiple forms together without losing data.